# Translate Android project with JUniversal

Tags: java, android, ios, code-translation

I am using JUniversal to translate Java classes of android project to Objective-C
after installing J2Objc And clone juniversal and jsimple on Mac OS X (Yosemite) from this [Link](http://juniversal.org/getting-started/) , when i run below command into terminal :

```
./gradlew build install javaToObjectiveC -x test
```

it shows me error :

> :libraries:jsimple-io:javaToObjectiveC FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':libraries:jsimple-io:javaToObjectiveC'.
>     Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 4
> - Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

Also the file **.bash_profile** in $HOME directory is defined :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/emaar/env/gradle
export M2_HOME=$HOME/env/maven
export JAVA_HOME2=/usr/libexec/java_home
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
export J2OBJC_HOME=/Users/emaar/env/j2objc
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$J2OBJC_HOME:$JAVA_HOME
```

when i use :

```
$ ./gradlew build install javaToCSharp -x test
```

it shows **BUILD SUCCESSFUL** with No Error

Also i try command :

```
./gradlew build install javaToObjectiveC -x test --stacktrace
```

> translating /Users/emaar/jsimple/libraries/jsimple-io/src/main/java/jsimple/pushnotifications/PushNotificationsReceiver.java
>   :libraries:jsimple-io:javaToObjectiveC FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':libraries:jsimple-io:javaToObjectiveC'.
>     Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 4
> - Try:
>     Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is:
>     org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':libraries:jsimple-io:javaToObjectiveC'.
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
>     at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
>     at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>     at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>     at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
>     at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
>     at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 4
>     at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
>     at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
>     at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:60)
>     at org.juniversal.buildtools.gradle.support.GradleJavaExec.exec(GradleJavaExec.java:59)
>     at org.juniversal.buildtools.common.JavaToObjectiveC.translateSourceType(JavaToObjectiveC.java:98)
>     at org.juniversal.buildtools.common.Translator.translate(Translator.java:78)
>     at org.juniversal.buildtools.gradle.JavaToObjectiveCTask.translate(JavaToObjectiveCTask.java:59)
>     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>     at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>     ... 47 more
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 17.897 secs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was Gradle Problem,Download and set Gradle and set on .bash_profile
after test :

> gradle -version

and get answer, problem fixed .